# How to pass user agent stylesheet css

Tags: css, user-agent

I'm trying to set the background-color to red, but doesn't work because of *user agent stylesheet*. 
I've tried the `<!DOCTYPE html>` but nothing change.
Please help. Thanks.
[image]

I've paste the code here https://jsfiddle.net/z1smp8on/1/ 
The problem is when i click to the 4th option, it will use *user agent stylesheet* instead of my style 
[image]

Comment: Hi, @fudu. Welcome. You'll need to show some code / and a minimum example somehow. There's no way we can really tell what is happening- or what stuff you are using - just from that image. the user-agent is staying it... so, you might want to see if there's a way to set it's appearance to none?

Comment: Try creating a simplified example like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4tp71joL/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I've upload the code to https://jsfiddle.net/z1smp8on/

Comment: The problem is when i click to the 4th option, it will use "user agent stylesheet" instead of my style.

Comment: Ok. But - is there anything else we need to know? Are you using a special package? How would a docktype help? Is it a specific browser? You'll need to put in more work - if you want strangers to helpyou. : )

Comment: I don't think so, i'm using default magento, but this is style problem, i guess.

Comment: Yeah. That's really really important. Magento - is like "A PROBLEM" in general... - so, we definitely need to know that.

Comment: In the code you just put in the jsfiddle - there's inline styles - that make it red. and - all of that dynamic Magento stuff - isn't going to work in the jsfiddle - so, please strip it down: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I've changed it to minimal, please check https://jsfiddle.net/z1smp8on/1/ . Oh, and this issue come only from Chrome.

Comment: It's red in that fiddle you are showing us. isn't that what you want? BTW: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @sheriffderek, please check my 2nd image on the post, when you click 4th option and then click some where else, you will the see error.

Comment: its should be the red, but the user agent stylesheet override it with !important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fount it.
All i have to do is use this instead of normal style tag.

```
background: linear-gradient(red, red)
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(48, 48, 48)
```

Thanks all for your help.